# Preload content of just one div with Jquery animated Preloader

Tags: jquery, html, preloader, image-preloader

I have a portfolio website with all the images in one container div. I currently have a JQuery preloader on the site which works great, it shows a loading bar and when it reaches 100% the website fades in. I'm wondering if I can just get this preloader in the one div that contains all my images and how I acheive that.

The plugin i'm using is QueryLoader and it's called using this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("body").queryLoader2({
    barColor: "#099",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    percentage: true,
    barHeight: 1,
    completeAnimation: "fade"
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks for your ideas in advance. The website is here: [www.samskirrowdesign.com](http://www.samskirrowdesign.com)

Comment: Whats the html for the preloader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havent worked with the preloader but I will take a shot at it.  I assume the html for the preloader would have to be inside the images div as well as the images.

```
<script>
  $("#divId").load(function(){
        $(this).queryLoader2({
            barColor: "#099",
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            percentage: true,
            barHeight: 1,
            completeAnimation: "fade"
        });
  });
</script>
```